# Editing the record not displaying the youtube link in edit page using php

Tags: php

I have property records displaying on my page.Property related data like property type,price,Sqfts and you-tube link is present in my records.Once i edit the page it is not displaying the youtube link in my edit page it is displaying as like this

[image]

In Console it is displaying the code like this:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <div class="field-label">Youtube Link</div>
    <input type="text" name="youtube_link" id="youtube_link" value="<iframe width=" 560"="" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/fmKWuAVt1vI" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen="">"  required&gt;
</div>
```

I have written the code as follows:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <div class="field-label">Youtube Link</div>
    <input type="text" name="youtube_link" id="youtube_link" value="<?php echo $oppointArr['youtube_link'];?>"  required>
</div>
```

I have inserted the URL in database as in this format:

```
 <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/kPGxWaIhLmk" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: What is the result of $oppointArr?

Comment: @ShivaniPatel in textbox it is displaying only "<iframe width=  thats it as shared in image

Comment: @ShivaniPatel added code how it is displaying in console as well.

Comment: But I have check the code in local system and it works perfect. It only display link of you tube. So, I just want to check that what is the value of  $oppointArr['youtube_link'] ?

Comment: @ShivaniPatel in console the value is displaying like this : <iframe width=" 560"="" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/fmKWuAVt1vI" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen="">

Comment: what about $oppointArr ? i think these return array so just put the return response of $oppointArr so we can help you in batter way.

Comment: _“In Console it is displaying the code like this”_ - the syntax highlighting should make it apparent immediately, what the problem is … You neglected to properly escape the data you are inserting into the value attribute. That data contains double quote characters itself, so it of course breaks the syntax. The content of the value attribute you created _is_ `<iframe width=`, and nothing more. You want to use https://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Input html is breaking with double ("), to fix this you can use single quote (') in value attribute

```html
<div class="form-group col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <div class="field-label">Youtube Link</div>
    <input type="text" name="youtube_link" id="youtube_link" value='<?php echo $oppointArr['youtube_link'];?>'  required>
</div>
```